# logstash + elasticsearch : reloads the same data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Managed to get logstash (1.3.1) to send data to elasticsearch (0.9.5).

My logstash conf file setup is

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.5/logs/*.*"]
   }

}
 output {
  stdout { } 
    elasticsearch_http {
    host => "localhost"
    port => 9200
   }
 }
```

The data is stored in ES  under index logstash-2013.12.xx

However, if i restart logstash, lets say next day - the same data is reloaded into a new index. Even if i restart again, the document count doubles in the index.

Seems like logstash re-reading the data and ES is also duplicating the documents.

Is there a way to not reload in logstash or not duplicate in ES or do  BOTH.

Comment: Logstash normally keeps a `.sincedb` file to track file progress. Maybe try running with `-v` to see if anything is going wrong with that. Does it have write permission on the sincedb's path? You might try specifying a sincedb path manually, so you can have a bit more control over it.

Comment: Oh, also this bug is probably relevant since you look to be on Windows: [LOGSTASH-1587: Windows - file input - sincedb / start_position is ignored](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1587)

Comment: @Rutter Thanks for there reference and reply. yes, i tried this on Windows. However, Using logstash 1.3.1.. hoping that it was all fixed !  Looks like there are still elementary issues with ES/Logstash. Might try on linux and see. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran across this issue with Logstash 1.3.3 as well. The relevant bug report on Logstash Jira is [LOGSTASH-429 File Input - .sincedb file is broken on Windows](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-429). There has also been a patch created by Boyd Meier.

This patch has also been pulled into Jordan Sissel's ruby-filewatch git repository for inclusion in a later version however it just hasn't made it in yet.

The issue comes from Logstash using the file inode which always returns 0 on Windows. Boyd Meier uses the File ID to get an identifier for the file to bypass the issue. This file id remains the same until the file is deleted from the volume.

If you're comfortable doing a bit of patching you can patch the change in from Jordan Sissel's ruby-filewatch git repository. For 1.3.3 that I have only just patched and am in the process of testing against test log files the steps were:

1. Download ruby-filewatch zip file from Github: [Jordan Sissel's ruby-filewatch
   git repository](https://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-filewatch)
2. Unzip the zip file you downloaded to a new directory
3. I had to make a change to the Ruby-filewatch\lib\filwatch\tail.rb
   file -> Line 10 which reads require "JRubyFileExtension.jar". I had
   to change to require "java/JRubyFileExtension.jar" as otherwise I
   was getting an error that it wasn't able to find the jar file when
   trying to read a file. For reference that makes the whole line appear as: `require "java/JRubyFileExtension.jar" if defined? JRUBY_VERSION`
4. Open logstash-1.3.3-flatjar.jar file in 7-Zip
5. Drag and drop the java directory from ruby-filewatch into the root
   folder in 7-Zip
6. Drag and drop all the files from the ruby-filewatch\lib\filewatch
   folder into the filewatch folder in 7-Zip, overwriting any existing
   files

Now when you run it against multiple log files you should find that sincedb contains more than one entry and the entries appear similar to 1717916447-2604966-851968 0 2 428312038. If you're having trouble finding the sincedb file and haven't set sincedb_path in your config file it can be found in the home directory of the user running the jar. If this is your user you can get to it easily using Windows key + Run -> %USERPROFILE% -> OK.

As always take care when patching and test thoroughly before deploying to production systems.

Comment: It does not look like this has been fixed in version 1.4.0 (according to the bug ticket). Is it the case ?

Comment: Yes, 1.4.0 also needs this patch. Worked for me, the only difference in my case is that logstash was not packed in jar, so I just replaced all filewatch *.rb files to patched ones (one new file added, winhelper.rb), and had to put 'java' folder into 'lib', so that 'require "java/JRubyFileExtension.jar"' line would work.

Comment: still not fixed in 1.4.2. I am seriously considering forking the whole thing in Java, this thing is full of bugs. jlogstash :-)

Comment: @TonyBenBrahim I'm not seeing the duplicate data for Logstash 1.4.2. win8 x64, with logstash either as a service or on the commandline, `start_position => "beginning"`, not specifying createdb path. And when I stop/start logstash, it doesn't reload the same data

Comment: Last status of this bug : https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/2. Sumed up : the 3rd lib has been fixed (filewatch v0.6.1 released) but LogStash 1.4 still with v0.5. Awaiting logStash to release.