# Using logstash and elasticseach

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm actually using node-bunyan to manage log information through elasticsearch and logstash and I m facing a problem.

In fact, my log file has some informations, and fills great when I need it.

The problem is that elastic search doesn't find anything on

> http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/

I have an empty object and so, I cant deliver my log to kibana.

Here's my logstash conf file :

```
input {
    file {
        type => "nextgen-app"
        path => [ "F:\NextGen-dev\RestApi\app\logs\*.log" ]
        codec => "json"
    }   
}

output {

  elasticsearch {
 host => "localhost"
 protocol => "http"
 }

}
```

And my js code :

```
log = bunyan.createLogger({
      name: 'myapp',
      streams: [
        {
          level: 'info',
          path: './app/logs/nextgen-info-log.log'
        },
        {
          level: 'error',
          path: './app/logs/nextgen-error-log.log'
        }
      ]
    })

router.all('*', (req, res, next)=>
      log.info(req.url)
      log.info(req.method)
      next()
    )
```

NB : the logs are well written in the log files. The problem is between logstash and elasticsearch :-/

EDIT : querying http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/ gives me "{}" an empty JSON object
Thanks for advance

Comment: what is the output of `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v` ?

Comment: It returns only : "health status index pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size "

Comment: alright.. which version of ES are you using? Also, please restart the logstash agent and check its logs for any errors or warnings..

Comment: The version 1.5.1. I restarted logstash(v1.4.2), and no problems in the log files

Comment: try adding a message manually using `logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { elasticsearch { host => localhost } }'` and typing something. this should add an index to ES which you can verify by using the command above or by typing `http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty`

Comment: I've had similar issues before with single-node ES instances when the space on my disk dived below 10%, which is the default watermark (see http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html#disk). Check your ES logs or post them above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we managed to fix this and other problems with Logstash not processing files correctly on Windows:

1. Install the ruby-filewatch patch as explained here:
   [logstash + elasticsearch : reloads the same data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592142/logstash-elasticsearch-reloads-the-same-data)
2. Properly configure the Logstash input plugin:

   > ```
   > input {
   >   file {
   >       path => ["C:/Path/To/Logs/Directory/*.log"]
   >       codec => json { }
   >       sincedb_path => ["C:/Path/To/Config/Dir/sincedb"]
   >       start_position => "beginning"
   >   }
   > }
   >
   > ...
   > ```

"sincedb" keeps track of your log files length, so it should have one line per log file; if not, then there's something else wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I read and tried the doc, but it seems that I cant find the .jar file at the 4 point : "Open logstash-1.3.3-flatjar.jar file in 7-Zip" . I dont have anything like this in logstash

Answer (score 2):

Your output scope looks not complete. Here's the list of the output parameters http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch

Please, try:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "nextgen-app"
        path => [ "F:\NextGen-dev\RestApi\app\logs\*.log" ]
        codec => "json"
    }   
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
        port => 9200
        protocol => "http"
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can try the transport protocol:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
        port => 9300
        protocol => "transport"
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

I also recommend using Kibana as a data viewer. You can download it at https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana