# Logstash loads the same data to same index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I loaded the data using logstash to ES.

I have a csv file, two columns, loaded using logstash basic file as below.

```
    input {
    file {
        path => "/Users/gibbs/Documents/search/mini_system_data_new.csv"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => [
               "secure_flag",
               "mini_system_key"
        ]
        separator => ","
        }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["path", "host"]
  }
}
output {
    stdout
    {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
     elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
        index => "mini_system"
        document_id => "%{mini_system_key}"
    }
}
```

I didn't create index at the time of loading. I realised and created the index but I didn't stop logstash. So it loaded partial data.

With an assumtion, I restarted logstash but it didn't load. I understand to avoid [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592142/logstash-elasticsearch-reloads-the-same-data). But Here I have custom ID field and this issue should not happen. But the missed data not loaded.

As a worst option, I recreated the index and restarted logstash. But no help here.

Any suggestion to load the data back?

**EDIT:**

I think logstash creats a reference to the file name. I renamed the data file and restarted. It loads the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`sincedb_path`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#_tracking_of_current_position_in_watched_files).

Logstash maintains the status of processed files in this location. If you delete this file and restart logstash, it will read the file again.

Moreover, I don't think you need to create an index for inserting data in elasticsearch. There is a feature called [Dynamic Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html) (Unless you have disabled it smh). Elasticsearch will try to infer the mapping from the data automatically.

So, the data you have missed might have been missed because of an incorrect format. CSV Filter filters out the badly formatted rows. Try to check the data with stdout by removing the CSV filter.

Comment: Yes. I got this. I don't need to delete that file. I need to set that synced_path not to output anything. This is also an option redirecting to `/dev/null`

Comment: Yeah. you could do that as well. forgot to mention it.